# jQuery change number inside a name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm writing some JavaScript to clone a table row containing form elements.

It's working well so far but there's one piece I can't quite figure out.

The element names have a number which increases with every row.

E.g:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="name[0][abc]" /></td>
            <td><button class="add-row-button">+</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="name[1][abc]" /></td>
            <td><button class="add-row-button">+</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need the cloned row to update the number. There are multiple fields in each row which need this updated number so I can't just include the new name in the jQuery code. What I think has to happen is I need get the name, use a regex replace, then update the attribute.

Here's my current (simplified for the example) jQuery:

```
// Current num of elements. Names are 0 based so this will be the number used
// for the new name.
var formRowCount = $('table tr').length;

$('.add-row-button').click(function() {
    // Clone the last row.
    $(this).closest('tr').last().clone().insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));

    // Set the new field selector.
    var $newRow = $(this).closest('tr').next();

    $newRow.find('input[type="text"]').val('');

    formRowCount++;
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. Before `formRowCount++;` I need to get the current element name and update the number with `formRowCount`.

Comment: It makes more sense to me to use `"name[abc][]"` and adjust the server-side code instead

Comment: If you know `formRowCount` why do you need to know the value x in `name[x][abc]`? - All you have to do is use `'name="name[' + formRowCount + '][abc]"'` ...or is there something you're not telling us?

Comment: That's what I'm leaning towards too. I was hoping to figure this out but altering the PHP is the backup plan.

Comment: @Popnoodles I would have to hardcode it for all the input elements in the row. The code I posted was just a basic version. The version I'm working on has 10 form elements per row. I guess I could do that for each element but I'd prefer to find a way to use the existing name attr instead of hardcoding. Less room for error if the names change or something in the future.

Comment: I would consider that important information that should be in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, you can use regex if you want.

```
var formRowCount = $('table tr').length;

$('.add-row-button').click(function() {

    // Clone the last row and insert it.
    $(this).closest('tr').last().clone().insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));

    // Select the input field
    var $newInput = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input[type="text"]');

    // Update the input value and name attribute
    var newName = $newInput.attr('name').replace(/^(name\[)\d+(\].+)$/, '$1' + formRowCount + '$2');
    $newInput.val('').attr('name', newName);

    // Update the number
    formRowCount++;

});
```

Comment: Perfect... I'll give this a test now.